# How to make header fixed but not hiding the content via CSS and HTML?

Tags: html, css, responsive

I'm trying to make a page in HTML and CSS that looks something similar to this picture:
[image: picture]

But whenever I try to do it, the content `div` goes behind the header `div` and I should do margin-top to get it down, but I think that it's a bad idea for responsive design...

This is the CSS code I tried:

```
.header{
    width:83%;
    height:62%;
    background: url('bg.jpg');
    position:fixed;
}
```

Comment: if your position is fixed I think it will normally follow you around if you scroll down or up.. have you tried removing it? or does `.header`have a parent?

Comment: @KimOliveros but the problem is that the .content div goes behind the .header div and i can't see it

Comment: add a `z-index` then

Comment: also can you post your codes on jsfiddle and post the link here so we could get a proper view of whats happening on your page

Comment: @KimOliveros i want it to go directly BELOW the .header div.

Comment: remove `position: fixed;` from the `.header` css.

Answer (score 1):

you may use `flex` for the positionning and scrolling.

The basic template could be made of 2 elements `<header>` and `<main>`.

example

```css
html {
  height:100%;
  }
body {
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:column;
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
  }
main {
  flex:1;/* fills whole space left */
  overflow:auto;/* i scroll if space too short */
  background:yellow;/* see me */
  }
```

```html
<header> any content here , <br/>no matter my height</header>
<main> content all the way down, i'll be scrolling if necessary</main>
```

and with any content:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
main {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
  background: yellow;
}
/* extra demo purpose */
nav ul {
  display: flex;
}
header {background:red;}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>HTML Ipsum Presents</h1>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Clients</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<main>
<h1>HTML Ipsum Presents</h1>

<p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em> Mauris
  placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis
  tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>

<h2>Header Level 2</h2>

<ol>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
  <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
</ol>

<blockquote>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna. Cras in mi at felis aliquet congue. Ut a est eget ligula molestie gravida. Curabitur massa. Donec eleifend, libero at sagittis mollis, tellus est malesuada tellus, at luctus turpis
    elit sit amet quam. Vivamus pretium ornare est.</p>
</blockquote>

<h3>Header Level 3</h3>

<ul>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
  <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
</ul>

<pre><code>
#header h1 a { 
 display: block; 
 width: 300px; 
 height: 80px; 
}
</code></pre>
  </main>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, the `body` will be become scrollable when it overflows the window.

If you just want the portion with the text in it to be scrollable, specify it on the element and make sure it only occupies enough space to fit inside the window (so the body doesn't become scrollable).

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

#header {
  font-size: 26px;
}

#content {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: calc(100% - 36px); // accounts for height of header, occupies rest of available height
}
```

That's one way, I'd prefer giving the `body` `display: flex` though. It'll automatically account for the rest of the available space.

```
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/JackHasaKeyboard/zhjsocfv/4/